# Don't update my versioncode apk

Tags: apk

Generating my apk does not update my versioncode.
already be changed inside the manifest and build.grandle
When analyzing apk does not update the apk, it keeps the versioncode 1.1.9, and therefore I can not update it in the play store.

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.dese.diario"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize"
    android:versionCode="22"
    android:versionName="1.2.2"
    >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
    <!-- To auto-complete the email text field in the login form with the user'Theme emails -->


    <!-- <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" /> -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAPTURE_VIDEO_OUTPUT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <protected-broadcast android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="false" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:replace="icon,android:theme">

   .....



 </application>

</manifest>
```

build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.3'
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.dese.diario"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 22
        versionName "1.2.2"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true

    }
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias 'AMDI'
            keyPassword 'safa2017'
            storeFile file('C:KeyDiario/KeyDiario.jks')
            storePassword 'safa2017'
        }

        debug {

            /* storeFile file('keystore/debug.keystore')
             keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
             keyPassword 'android'
             storePassword 'android'*/
            keyAlias 'AMDI'
            keyPassword 'safa2017'
            storeFile file('C:KeyDiario/KeyDiario.jks')
            storePassword 'safa2017'
        }
    }


.....


}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Analyze APK:

[image]

Comment: i think you analyze old apk, try to generate signed apk and save other then project location and then analyse signed apk

Comment: I create my apk with date and time. 
I analyze the apk that generates most recent and still does not update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem, 
when apk is generated.
Change the value of:

```
 minifyEnabled false
```

to

```
  minifyEnabled true
```

Answer (score 1):

I also have this problem after updating android studio to version 3

after sometime, I realize the apk folder location is changed from 
"app\" to "app\release\"

therefore, the solution is to use the apk in app\release folder